# Is it possible to get sound raw data with 8KHz sample data rate, not 44.1KHz?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, pcm

I am using the flash platfrom to create a player that will load sound that have 8KHz sampla data rate, but the default data rate is 44.1KHz.

Is this somehow possible?

Is it even possible to use also 4KHz?

Any idea about this?

Also is it possbile to get 16bit sample, not the default 32bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link, this may helps you:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

and yes you can load sound that have 8KHz sampla data by changing bit rate of mic as

```
 **mic.rate = 8;**
```

I will recommend you to use the 12khz atleast. 8khz is not supported by many sound cards on many operating systems. 8khz will sound slow and drowsy in some cases. This is my personal experience not documented by adobe since its not there issue but the sound drivers and OS.

at 8 khz, the sound was recorded perfectly but it was not playing at all,
and at 11Khz, it played with high pitch.

When you use 8000 samples per second, the playRecorded function isn't calling **e.data.writeFloat(sample)** enough times. It calls it 16379 times instead of 16834 times ( 8192 * 2 ) like the other rates ( 11025, 22050, 44100 ). If you call **e.data.writeFloat( 0 )** for the remaining 455 times then you will have a good Sound object for playback.